# Calculating a coefficient for a formal power series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

My textbook has a whole bunch of exercises on finding some coefficient inside a formal power series. Unfortunately, there aren't any examples on how to do so, especially since many of the series expand to infinite power series and the binomial theorem seems to not apply.

For example, I'm asked to find the coefficient of $x^8$ in the series expansion of $(1-x)^{-7}$, and to find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the series expansion of $x^6(1-2x)^{-5}$. How would I proceed? I'd like some general method to do these problems, not just the numerical answer for these two problems.

Sorry if this seems to be a really dumb question.

Comment: As long as they are asking for the coefficient of a particular monomial, there is no need to expand infinite power series; just go up to the degree asked for.

Comment: How would one go about doing so?

Comment: Well, for instance you can truncate the geometric series $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ after $x^8$ when computing the coefficient of $x^8$ in $(1-x)^{-7}$. Computing $(1+x+\cdots+x^8)^7$ is maybe not the most efficient way to find this, but it is important to realise that it is a perfectly valid method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following techniques should suffice for problems as simple as the ones you list.

1. Use binomial theorem to find any coefficient of $(a + bx)^n$, for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
   A simpler approach is to factor out the $a^n$ to get $(1 + \frac{b}{a}x)^n$, and then to treat $(\frac{b}{a}x)$ as a single unit.
   With this approach, you really only have to know two expansions:

- For $n > 0$, $\displaystyle (1 + x)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}x^k$.
- For $n > 0$, $\displaystyle (1 - x)^{-n} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty {{n + k - 1} \choose {k}} x^k$.

2. Multiplying by a factor of $x^m$ is easy -- this just shifts all the terms over.  For instance, if you want to find the coefficient of $x^8$ in $x^3 \cdot (\text{other stuff})$, just find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(\text{other stuff})$.  The $x^5$ term will then be multiplied by $x^3$, resulting in the desired $x^8$ term.

Comment: Your $(1 - x)^{-n} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1} x^n$ has coefficients that are clearly $n - 1$ degree polynomials in $k$.